# Send filepath as getURL parameter Django2

Tags: python, django

I want to send a file url as a get parameter:

```
$.get("/django_route/"+ encodeURIComponent(fileUrl), function(res){
    console.log(res)
})
```

But it looks like Django is interpreting my encoded URI component as an actual URI...

Is this kind of thing possible with Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's interpreting it as a URL because you're sending it in the URL. Do you perhaps want to sent it a a querystring? If so, then do that:

```
 $.get("/django_route/?filepath="+ encodeURIComponent(fileUrl), ...
```

Comment: I didn't realize Django picked those up. Thanks!